# position set to 0 after compact() of ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

Typically, after a compact() to a ByteBuffer is called, I see that the new position will be set to the old limit such that the buffer is ready for a put().

But sometimes, I see that the position is 0 in a ByteBuffer (and limit = capacity) after a call to compact().  If so, would this happen only when position = capacity (or position = limit) before the call to compact?

The javadoc for ByteBuffer says "The buffer's position is then set to n+1 and its limit is set to its capacity.", but I seem to see the position set to 0 in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would happen if you've removed everything from the buffer, so it becomes the same as a `clear().` That would imply that `position = limit` beforehand.